# Why printing on 10x15cm paper always cropped?

Tags: printing

I have Epson SC-P800 printer and I use LR for printing.
I print on Hahnemuhle 10x15 photo cards which are 100x150mm.
To crop image in LR I use 4x6 aspect ratio which is the same as 10x15 (1:1.5).
Then I use custom size in Print module:
Paper Size: Width: 100mm Height: 150mm and Non-printable area is 0 for each of 4 sides (screenshot is attached).
In Layout I use 0mm margins and Height/Width = 150mm/100mm

Driver setting are default.

When printed, image cropped approx 3-5mm by each side.

I am attaching original image and image of the print and hopefully you'll be able to see what I mean.

How can this be fixed?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

P.S.updating this question with more relevant screenshot of image in Print module - you can see there that printed image is cropped.

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

I decided to print on more standard paper 4x6 inches or 102x152mm:
1) first I cropped image to 4x6 ratio:
[image]
2) then I selected 4x6 Sheet Feeder Borderless Auto Expand in Print module:
[image]
as you see, there is author's signature is visible on the bottom and there is space between image border and dog's tail.
3) result on 102x152 paper is cropped (not space to the right of dog's tail and no author's signature):
[image]

So, I assume that there is no way to correctly print images on small papers when cropping really matters on Epson SC-P800.

Comment: Hunch: Try unchecking Zoom to fill and Rotate to fit.

Comment: 10x15 or 4x6 is 2x3 ratio not 1:1.5

Comment: Stan, tried this, did not helped.

Comment: Remus Rigo, isn't 2x3 = 1x1,5?:)

Answer (score 2):

Do you print without borders? If yes, the printer needs to expand the image to a larger area to ensure that there are no white stripes left. Even more expensive printers do that. If you need borderless images exactly 10x15 cm in size, consider printing more on a larger paper and then cut to size.

Comment: Thank you! You probably right. This is why Hahnemuhle have this instruction on how to print on their cards - http://www.hahnemuehle.com/fileadmin/user_upload/pdf/dfa/Anleitungen/DFA__Anleitung_Fotokarten_Drucken_EN.pdf I will try that and will let you know.

Comment: P.S. updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try unchecking "zoom to fill".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this did not helped. P.S. I have updated question with screen shot from Print module.

Comment: by the way, Zoom to fill have no sense in the case because 4x6 (crop ration) and print size 100x150 are the same ratio, so nothing to 'zoom'.

Answer (score 1):

Done using Epson print settings in Photoshop CS6...So i've had the same cropping problem with my sc p00 and i did some test prints at different settings. The method that works closest to what you need is as follows...I first made the image exact to the size i was printing in my case 8.5x11. that's the aspect and actual size in photoshop. In the printer settings/paper setting/expansion I chose retain size. In the "position and size" I set the scale to 100% checked "center" and left "scale to fit media" UNCHECKED. These setting will no longer crop your photo but the borderless isn't perfect. On right side there is a hair line of border. If I figure out how to eliminate that slight bit of border I'll update.

Comment: Thank you for an answer! I think this solution is the best for now. But it does not suit for my specific media - Hahnemuhle Photo Cards. The white line on the border should be cut and id the media cut, it is highly visible because is tas rounded corners.

Comment: I think I need to experiment more with different border sizes, but it is really time consuming and probably not worth spending so much time for my current project.... Would be happy to hear on how you improve your method!

Answer (score 0):

On my EPSON Stylus Photo R2880, if I want to print borderless, I need to select a different paper size.

In the print menu, some of the paper options are:

- 10x15cm (4x6 in)
- 10x15cm (4x6 in) (Sheet feeder - Borderless (auto-expand))
- 10x15cm (4x6 in) (Sheet feeder - Borderless (retain size))

The first option will always give me a ~3mm border. The other two don't

Comment: Yes, first I selected 10x15cm (4x6 in) (Sheet feeder - Borderless (auto-expand)) from menu, but this is not exact size of 100x150 which my paper is (the option you are referring to gives size 102x152mm). So then I created custom size which measures exactly 100x150 with zero borders.